# Mat date range picker dates wrong position

Tags: css, typescript, daterangepicker

I added the date range picker and the month+dates are at the wrong position.
No changes were made at the css file so I do not understand it.
[Picture of Rangepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVcd2.png)

```
                    <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker" [formGroup]="range">
                    <input matStartDate placeholder="Start Date" formControlName="start" (dateChange)="onChange()">
                    <input matEndDate placeholder="End Date" formControlName="end" (dateChange)="onChange()">
                </mat-date-range-input>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This problem doesn't seem to appear on the [demo](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples), so there must be something in your project breaking it. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.